# Append a parameter to the URL using string.format

Tags: vb.net, string.format

I am trying to append a parameter to the URL...here is the code

```
 Function SendingRequest(item as String) As String

    Dim URL As String
    URL = String.Format("http://localhost/SomeService/Type?id={0}", item)
    WebRequest.Create(URL)
    Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
            Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
            Return responseFromServer
            reader.Close()
            response.Close()
  End Function
```

This is not returning the response...where as when i pass the hard coded url like WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/SomeService/Type?id=ABC") i am able to get the response...what might be the problem in appending the parameter????

Comment: nothing, i guess; should work; the only thing for the safety reason try to trim input parameter like: item.Trim() and check if the item is nothing

Comment: When you run the code, what is the URL that is generated?

Comment: this is a mvc application this is the url that is hit when i run the code http://localhost/SomeController/SendingRequest/ABC

Comment: huh..that wass a problem in global.asax file.. something with routemap